# Client Authentication when using Service Bus for Windows Server

Tags: authentication, servicebus

I'm currently working on a project where we use the Service Bus for Windows Server queues and topics for handling messaging between clients and server. Currently I'm looking into how to handle authentication of the clients and believe we need to use SAS. The clients communicating with the queues can be using both rest and the .net api. I have tried to find resources on best practices especially on how to handle token generation and distribution. For example should we create a service for this that the calling client can connect to providing the access key which would then generate a token returned to the client. Ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

/Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the WindowsTokenProvider and a Windows user account.

1. First add a valid Windows user to the Bus with Send permissions on your queue/topic. (You can do this in code or via service bus explorer.)
2. **Then for the Rest API client authentication over Http** - You need to post over a valid UserName/Pwd to the STS then add the resulting token to the authorization header of the actual post to the queue. 
   [You can see how to do this here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678274/not-able-to-use-rest-api-for-service-bus-for-windows-server-1-1-onpremises/21754862#21754862)
3. **For the .Net client over TCP** - 
   Run your client as the same valid windows user, and then call the STS with these implicit credentials by using the TokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider.

3.1 If you are using the NetMessagingBinding for your client (WCF) then do the following:

```
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace", serverName));
        var uris = new List<Uri> {uri};
        var securityBehavior = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
            {
                TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider(uris)
            };

       var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(contract, new NetMessagingBinding(), new EndpointAddress(serviceBusEndpointAddress));
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(securityBehavior);
```

3.2 NB - The code above will take the implicit credentials of the current principal and pass them across. However, you can explicitly pass in credentials like this:

```
         var securityBehavior = new TransportClientEndpointBehavior
            {
                TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider(uris, new NetworkCredential("myUser", "myPassword"))
            };
```

3.3 Or if you just use the plain .NetClient you can do the same like this:

```
         var uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace", serverName));
         var uris = new List<Uri> {defaultUri};
        var messagingFactorySettings = new MessagingFactorySettings();
        messagingFactorySettings.TokenProvider = 
          TokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider(uris, new 
          NetworkCredential("myUser", "myPassword"));
          .....
        var factory = MessagingFactory.Create("endpoint", messagingFactorySettings);
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear in my initial question. I do believe that we will be able to use Windows integrated security for some clients and for that thanks a lot for the answer. But is there any best practices or recommendations when using SAS for clients like a 3rd party CRM system where we can't use Windows Accounts.

Comment: Sorry I havent used sas before. Sounds like you are half way there! Free to bump my answer if it was useful ;-).