# Service Bus for Windows Server SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

Hy,

I have a question to the Service Bus for Windows Server SDK. It is possible to access the Service Bus via the two ways

1. Service Bus for Windows Server SDK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/jj542419.aspx

1. REST

Is the Service Bus for Windows Server SDK also in the background a REST implementation so the SDK is only a wrapper and the code behind is also access the service bus with the help of REST?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the REST API is also possible for the Windows Server install of Service Bus.
And don't forget the 3rd one; AMQP ! ;)

The REST API reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh780717.aspx
An example on StackOverflow: [Not able to use REST API for Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1 (OnPremises)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678274/not-able-to-use-rest-api-for-service-bus-for-windows-server-1-1-onpremises)

It's mostly the security that is different from the 'Cloud version of Service Bus'

Comment: Hy, thank you for your answer. But behind the SDK everything also works with REST?

Best regards

Comment: Behind the SDK, only the management operations (create/check queue, namespace management, etc) seem to be using REST.  The actual message processing (sending / receiving) are using either AMQP or the SBMP protocol.

Comment: Hy, I'm a little bit confused about the different ways to access the service bus. Under the homepage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/jj193012%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) there are only decriped two ways to access the service bus (REST and over the .net SDK). But they don't wrote something about **AMQP**? On the following link (http://www.cloudcasts.net/devguide/Default.aspx?id=12007) the author wrote that **WCF** is the third option to access the service bus? Now I'm confusiod which of the two things (AMQP or WCF) works to access the service bus.

Best regards

Comment: I think a lot of things are because of the constant evoluation of the Service Bus.
WCF is indeed also a possibility, but that's mostly a different programming model that is using the sbmp behind the scenes, if I remember well.
AMQP has been added since last year only and therefore might not be available in all documentations yet.  But this page describes everything: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-amqp-overview/

Comment: Hy, so AMQP is also supported for the Service Bus for Windows Server 1.0? I found no exact information and read somewhere:

With the release of Service Bus 1.1, we are happy to announce that AMQP 1.0 support is now available in Service Bus Source: (http://blogs.technet.com/b/in_the_cloud/archive/2013/08/20/what-s-new-in-2012-r2-enabling-modern-apps-with-the-windows-azure-pack.aspx).

Comment: I believe you have to use Service Bus 1.1 to benefit from the AMQP support

Comment: Hy,

I have anothe question to the Service Bus SDK. Above we wrote that it supports SBMP and the AMQP Protcol. Not I looked up in the documentation and they wrote something about NET.TCP and nothing about SBMQ.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193012.aspx

Did the SDK uses NET.TCP or the SBMQ protcol?

Best regards