# HttpBinding for windows server service bus

Tags: wcf, service, wcf-binding, azureservicebus

Can we have a HTTP protocol binding using WCF to receive a message from windows server service bus on topic/subscription  ?

Comment: Is "yes, you can" the answer you are looking for? Do you know what duplex bindings are?

Comment: yes, service and client can communicate to each other. But here I need a WCF service to pull the messages published on topic, which binding should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only wcf Binding you can use is netmessagingbinding which runs over tcp not http. If you want to consume messages via http you will need to use the [windows service bus rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678274/not-able-to-use-rest-api-for-service-bus-for-windows-server-1-1-onpremises/21754862#21754862)